# EF6 DbUpdateConcurrencyExcpetion in Disconnected Scenario

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm struggling with a DbUpdateConcurrencyException in a disconnected scenario, using EF6 (Entity Framework 6) with a Oracle DB.

#### Basically my code looks like this (simplyfied):

```cs
//retrieve transfer object from db (with statusid = 2)
//do something
transfer.StatusId = 3;

using (TransferContext tc = new TransferContext())
{
    tc.Entry(transfer).State = EntityState.Modified;

    tc.SaveChanges();
}
```

#### EF logs the following SQL:

```
update "T_TRANSFER_SC"
   set "STATUS_ID" = :p0
where (("ID" = :p1) 
   and ("STATUS_ID" = :p2))
                 
                 
-- :p0: '3' (Type = Decimal)

-- :p1: '1' (Type = Decimal)

-- :p2: '3' (Type = Decimal)

-- Completed in 3 ms with result: 0
```

**Both the ID as well as STATUS_ID property are set to: Concurreny Mode = Fixed**.

As you can see the parameters p0 and p2 have the value 3, but p2 should have the value 2 (at least from my understanding), which is the old value of the property.

If I execute the code I get an **DbUpdateConcurrencyException** exception:
"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

The exception is relatable, because there is no record with ID = 1 and STATUS_ID = 3 in the database (record in db has values 1 and 2). What I don't understand, is why EF does not use the old value of STATUS_ID in the Where-Clause.

Am I missing something, or is this always the case when working with different contexts (disconnected)? And how do I fix this?

Comment: because the original entry (when it was attached) already had the STATUS_ID of 3. To resolve this, it should be enough to set its status after attaching it to the context (the tc.Entry() call), though it is dubious to alter the concurrency tokens manually.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Ok, I was sure I was missing something. So the original values are the values when first attached to the context (in my example the value 3, because the context never saw the value 2). Setting the status after attaching the object to the context will not work for me, because of the disconnected scenario the change to the property happens in a completely different part of my application. Is there no other way to track changes outside a context?

Comment: no, the entity has to be attached to the same context before the property is modified.